# my first Spring MVC with Mongo; mongosocketexception

Tags: spring, mongodb, maven, spring-data-mongodb

Hi I am using MongoDB with Spring MVC.
I am facing below issue-
"HTTP Status 500 - Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoSocketException".

Below are my project details.

POM.xml:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring framework START -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- mongo db driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
        <!-- <version>3.0.2</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jstl for jsp page -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet API -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency> -->


    <!-- JSP API -->
    <!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/jsp-api -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- spring mongo driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <!-- <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework END -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xbean</groupId>
        <artifactId>xbean-spring</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

WEB.XML is:

```
<display-name>SpringMVCMongo</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVCMongo</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVCMongo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


Dispatcher-servlet.xml is:


    <bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="54.172.243.152" />
    <property name="port" value="27005" />
</bean>
<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="smynapati" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="smynapati" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="authSource" value="admin" /> -->
</bean>
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg name="mongoCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials" /> -->
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test1" />
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" /> 
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.userlogin"/>
<bean id="ViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should upgrade `mongo-java-driver` version to at least `2.12.0`. This is the first version to introduce `MongoSocketException` (an unchecked exception replacement to a former one).

`spring-data-mongodb` version `1.5.2.RELEASE` is compiled with `mongo-java-driver` version `2.12.1` which is "older" than the one you've declared in your pom (`2.11.0`).

You should set it as the fixed dependency version for `mongo-java-driver`. Meaning change `mongo-java-driver` from  `2.11.0` to `2.12.1`

Comment: Hi thanks, it solved but i need one more suggestion.
where i have to mention the "authSource" parameter.
my parameter value is "authSource=admin", i should give this value with user name and password then only i can connect to it.
if you see my     dispatcher-servlet.xml file above i did commented authSource, because i am facing bean creation exception.

Comment: FYI, In stand alone component i use to give mongo credentials like below


MongoClient client = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("mongodb://smynapati:smynapati@12.123.123.123:27005/?authSource=admin"));

Comment: This is a completely different issue from the original one. You should post it as a new question. Hint: you should register a `MongoDbFactory` Spring bean

Comment: as you suggested, i raised one more question with subject "authsource in mongodb spring".
could you please add your suggestion there.

Answer (score 0):

A Found that your web.xml and **Dispatcher**-servlet.xml,

In Spring servlet name must be same as dispatcher name,
ie you should rename Dispatcher-servlet.xml to SpringMVCMongo-servlet.xml.

And Try the code.

All the Best.

Comment: ArjunKori, i changed it and could you please check this post "authsource in mongodb spring".